# Zip CSV files in a subfolder

Tags: python, csv, zip

I have multiple .csv files in a folder called `data`. I would like to loop through all these files, and zip all csv files having the same date in a .zip file:

- C:\users\data\20230914_Morning.csv
- C:\users\data\20230914_Evening.csv
- C:\users\data\20230914_Night.csv

So all these files will be cut from `data` and moved into a zip `20230914_data.zip`
`C:\users\data\20230914_data.zip`

And in `20230914_data.zip` we should have the three csv files above:

- 20230914_Morning.csv
- 20230914_Evening.csv
- 20230914_Night.csv

I've tried this code:

```
def zip_csv_files(folder_name, date):
    date_to_string = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    zipfile_name = f'{date_to_string}_data'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_name , 'w') as zipF:
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_name):
            if filename.endswith('.csv') and date_to_string in filename:
                zipF.write(filename, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        return zipfile_name
```

But I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] File not found: 'C:\users\data\20230914_data.zip'` when retrieving the file.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far. Its a pretty straightforward task and example abound. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've added the code used above. Please have a look.

Comment: They "will be" cut from `data`? Were files put in a _folder_ named `C:\users\data\20230914_data.zip` _before_ you ran the above code? (By the way, naming a folder `.zip` and then naming a zip file `_data` is very much not the convention. zip files end in `.zip`. A directory would not be named `.zip`, since only zip files should have that extension.)

Comment: Thank you @MarkAdler, I've updated the post to clarify that. And yes, the CSVs will be cut from ```data``` and all zipped into ```20230914_data.zip```.

Comment: When you run this code, what is the value of `folder_name`?

Comment: This `f'{date_to_string}_data'` should be `f'{date_to_string}_data.zip'`.

Comment: ```folder_name = C:\users\data```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you're getting that error message, but the problem is that you need the folder name along with the name that `listdir` found.

This:

```py
zipF.write(filename, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

needs to be this:

```py
zipF.write(os.path.join(folder_name, filename), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Also your zip file name should end with .zip:

```py
zipfile_name = f'{date_to_string}_data.zip'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @MarkAdler. I'm getting that error message because I can't find it (the .zip) in the src folder ```C:\users\data\```. I want the zip of the CSVs to be created in the same folder where there were the CSVs. + It's now creating a path inside the new folder (when unzipping it) so in ```20230914_data``` there's a new path ```20230914_data\users\data\```.

Comment: So you're saying that that error message is _not_ being produced by your code in the question. Then you need to include in your question what you're doing to get the error message. Where's _that_ code? Where are you running these scripts from? I.e. what directory are you in when you run them? Of course you're not going to find a file ending with `.zip` anywhere, since you never create such a file. You left the `.zip` off of the name in your script. See my answer. Finally, how are you seeing new paths when unzipping, if you can't find the file to unzip in the first place!